# nodejs ssh Connection use Promise return wrong value

Tags: node.js, promise

I got some problem of my nodejs program. All I want to do is use ssh connection to get the status from other service back.
My original code as below, it works but I want to make it more easy to understand.

```
function stopConnect() {
    const ContainerName = paths.getConnectService();
    const password = 'root';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getActiveState()
            .then((response) => {
                if (response === 'inactive') {
                    // ssh connection
                    ssh.connect({
                        host: 'localhost',
                        username: 'root',
                        password,
                        port: 62222
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            //execute ssh command and wait for response
                            ssh.execCommand(`application stop ${ContainerName}`)
                                .then(() => {
                                    resolve('stop docker container successfully');
                                });
                        })
                }
            })
    });
}
```

I want to reduce complex of nest for mantainance.So I try to split it into two functions, "stopConnect" and "sshCommandFunction" as below.

```
function stopConnect() {

    const ContainerName = paths.getConnectService();

    return isRunning()
        .then((isRunning) => {
            if (isRunning) {
                ssh.connect({
                    host: 'localhost',
                    username: 'root',
                    password: 'root',
                    port: 62222
                })
                    .then((
                    ) => {
                        return sshCommandFunction();
                    })
            }
        });
}

function sshCommandFunction() {
    const ContainerName = paths.getConnectService();

    return ssh.execCommand(`application stop ${ContainerName}`)
        .then(() => {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }).catch((error) => {
            return Promise.reject(new Error(error));
        });
}
```

I got a problem that "sshCommandFunction" return "undefined" always.
Is there any problem of my code ? Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.resolve();` is the same as `Promise.resolve(undefined);`

So this is where you got the undefined from.

If you want to return the value (if only one) from the execCommand, use this function:

```
    function sshCommandFunction() {
        const ContainerName = paths.getConnectService();

        return ssh.execCommand(`application stop ${ContainerName}`)
            .then((a) => {
                return Promise.resolve(a);
            }).catch((error) => {
                return Promise.reject(new Error(error));
            });
    }
```

Or even better, return whatever the execCommand returns:

```
    function sshCommandFunction() {
        const ContainerName = paths.getConnectService();

        return ssh.execCommand(`application stop ${ContainerName}`)
            .catch((error) => {
                return Promise.reject(new Error(error));
            });
    }
```